# Codeception How to delete cookie with phpbrowser

Tags: php, cookies, codeception

I don't understand why this simple example doesn't work with Codeception and Phpbrowser :

Acceptance test :

```
public function tryToTest(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $I->setCookie('test', 1);
    $I->amOnPage('/test.php');
    $I->dontSeeCookie('test');
}
```

test.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_COOKIE);

if (isset($_COOKIE['test'])){
    unset($_COOKIE['test']);
    setcookie('test', '', 1, '/');
    echo 'delete cookie';    
}
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

And the result I get in the console :

```
Try to test
Test  tests/acceptance/Membre/osefCest.php:tryToTest
Step  Don't see cookie "test"
Fail  Failed asserting that Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie Object    &0000000040bdf1ba000000010c93ce0d (
   'name' => 'test'
   'value' => 1
   'expires' => null
   'path' => '/'
   'domain' => ''
   'secure' => false
   'httponly' => true
   'rawValue' => '1'
) is null.
```

And the output Codeception :

```
array(1) {
    ["test"]=>
    string(1) "1"
}
delete cookie
array(0) {
}
```

The cookie seems to be deleted during the script but the test in Codeception say the opposite.
Is it normal ? How to delete a cookie and check it in Codeception ?

Thank you !